# Convert Digit into Letter

Tags: php

I have digit string and convert into letters.

```
$arr = str_split('12345');
Array
 (
  [0] => 1
  [1] => 2
  [2] => 3
  [3] => 4
  [4] => 5
 )
```

Now I want to Convert 1 = A, 2 = B, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest solution I can think of right now:

```
$arr = str_split('12345');
$arr2 = str_split('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');

foreach($arr as &$digit)
    $digit = $arr2[$digit-1];
```

note that `$digit` is passed to the loop by reference using a `&` symbol. That means that when you manipulate `$digit`, the respective array entry in `$arr` will be changed as well.

Comment: What do you mean? `0` should be translated to `.`?

Comment: So what should `0` become? And do you want to skip `.`s? You did not say that in your question.

Comment: Yes sir you are write.

Comment: Again...what should `0` be translated to?

Comment: $treegarden Basically this is price of product and I want to convert into simple code.

Comment: Yes I also want to convert 0 and . into letter

Answer (score 0):

By using [base_convert](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php), I made this:

```
$arr = str_split('12345');

foreach($arr as $something){
    if($something==1){
        $value=$something*10;
    }else{
        $value++;
    }
    echo base_convert($value, 10, 36);
}
```

Might not be the best solution but it is a solution. I'll explain what I did here.

In the docs it says:

> Digits in numbers with a base higher than 10 will be represented with the letters a-z, with a meaning 10, b meaning 11 and z meaning 35

So I just made sure 1=10,2=11,3=12,4=13,5=14 etc...

Result:
abcde

Answer (score 0):

Try getting them from their ASCII Code like this :

```
<?php
$arr = str_split('12345');
$str = chr($arr[0]+64);
echo ("str=".$str."\n");
?>
```

Comment: You need to do this in a foreach loop.